# Date format in Google Spreadsheet is not correct

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, date

Whenever entering the date e.g. `day-month-year`, it automatically changes to `month-day-year`. I went into format>number>more formats>more date and time formats, and I changed it to `day-month-year`. And again, when entering `day-month-year` e.g. `18-4-2014`, it changes it to `4-18-2014`, but when I click on the date, it shows as `18/4/2014` next to f<sub>x</sub> above the page.

So it looks like Google Spreadsheet is messing up. How to fix this?

Comment: You could put your comment as answer, it fixed my problem, thanks! If you put it as answer, I can mark it as answered.

Comment: If I enter 18-4-2014 it leaves it as 18-4-2014, but if I enter 5-2-2014, it changes it to 2-5-2014.. But now, the problem is solved by using Netherlands as locale. I am using the new spreadsheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to set the correct Local under the Spreadsheet's settings ("This affects formatting defaults, such as currency."). So if you want US.locale style (MM-DD-YYYY), then choose US.Locale. If you are in a different locale and want formatting